# how would I change this over to do a full text search instead of LIKE?

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search, search-engine, sql-like

after some researching I put this code together to search a mysql table in the db. while it works fine, it limit itself to match the words exactly as the user enters it. anyone know how to make it so that it matches my some sort of relevancy? I have been reading about the full text search but I cant really seem to grasp it.

for example, if you search for 'unanswered questions' in two fields, I want to be able to get result like that include the searched word(s) in any string that it show up in, and list it according to relevancy, like so (search results example output):
 - unanswered questions
 - answered questions
 - answer question
 - unanswered questions
 - unanswered questions
 - questions
 - answer

```
    $k = trim ($_GET['search']);
    $i = "";
    $terms = explode (" ", $k);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ";

    foreach ($terms as $each){
    $i++;

    if ($i == 1)
    $query .= "fld_title LIKE '%$each%' OR fld_keyword LIKE '%$each%'        ";

    else
    $query .= "OR fld_title LIKE '%$each%' OR fld_keyword LIKE '%$each%' ";
    }

     // connect
     include_once "connect.php"; //connect 2 db
     $query = mysql_query($query);
     $numrows = mysql_num_rows ($query);
    if ($numrows > 0){

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($query)){

    //
    //
    // echo out something here
    //
    //

    }

    }else
         {
        echo "No results found for <b>$k</b>";   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to do a fulltext search you have to:

Create a Fulltext index in the table (note the fields can't be BLOB)

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD FULLTEXT(field1, field2,...);
```

in your case:

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD FULLTEXT(fld_title, fld_keyword);
```

in php change

```
    $k = trim ($_GET['search']);
    $i = "";
    $terms = explode (" ", $k);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ";

    foreach ($terms as $each){
    $i++;

    if ($i == 1)
    $query .= "fld_title LIKE '%$each%' OR fld_keyword LIKE '%$each%'        ";

    else
    $query .= "OR fld_title LIKE '%$each%' OR fld_keyword LIKE '%$each%' ";
    }
```

for

```
$k = trim ($_GET['search']);
$query="SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(fld_title, fld_keyword) AGAINST ('".$k."')";
```

if you want to see the relevancy of the results:

```
$query="SELECT *, MATCH(fld_title, fld_keyword) AGAINST ('".$k."') as relevancy FROM table1 WHERE MATCH(fld_title, fld_keyword) AGAINST ('".$k."')";
```

The MATCH-AGAINST returns a number: 0 for no match or other depending on matching.

You can "order by relevancy", change the query for make more relevant the search... MATCH(fld_title, fld_keyword) AGAINST ('".$k."') > 0.5

Only one problem: the AGAINST part ($k for you) must be greater than 3 characters.